# Tikzcd basic example

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have this code:

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzcd}
    L   
    \ar[d, dash, dashed]  
    \ar[d, dash, dashed] 
    \\
    E
    \ar[d,dash,"<\infty \ \  \emph{separable}"] 
    \\
    F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Output:

[image]

How can I complete the code in order to have this? [image]

Comment: Can you complete your code to a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) It  will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an arrow with a custom `to path` as described in the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}
 \ar[dd, dash,dashed,
     "\text{something}" swap,
     to path={
           -- ([xshift=-1.5cm]\tikztostart.east)
           |- (\tikztotarget) [pos=0.25] \tikztonodes
     }]
    L   
    \ar[d, dash, dashed]  
    \ar[d, dash, dashed] 
    \\
    E
    \ar[d,dash,"<\infty \ \  \emph{separable}"] 
    \\
    F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```